# psql 9.1 reset size of the postgresql log file

Tags: logging, postgresql-9.1

My log file (postgresql-9.1-main.log) size use to be 3G  before rotation but a fews days ago it started to be 70G. I did not change anything.

```
pg_lsclusters   
Version Cluster   Port Status Owner    Data directory                     Log file   
9.1     main      5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main       /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log
```

So the log is not managed by PostgreSQL, but by the package since all the line related to the logging are commented out.

Is it possible that PostgreSQL Common relies on logrotate?
How can i reset the size of the log file to 3G?

Answer (score 0):

just had to go to `/etc/logrotate.d/postgresql-common` and make the changes.

```
/var/log/postgresql/*.log {
   daily        <----change from weekly to daily.
   rotate 31
   copytruncate
   delaycompress
   compress
   notifempty
   missingok
}
```